# Making React Component of list of posts and their comments below them from 2 API

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, axios

I'm Using Two API Endpoints in my React.js App and Axios so that it must list posts and their comments below them.

The Problem is I Can't Excute Two map functions inside each other to do that, I Googled the issue but I had no lead, I also thought using other JavaScript Functions like Reduce instead of map but I dont think it will work out.

### The 2 API Endpoints Are :

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1

### The Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './Postlist.css';

class Postlist extends Component {
  state = {
    posts: [],
    comments: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`).then(res => {
      const posts = res.data;
      this.setState({ posts });
    });

    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments`).then(res => {
      const comments = res.data;
      this.setState({ comments });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="jumbotron-div col s12">
          <ul className="collection">
            {this.state.posts.map(post => (
              <li
                key={post.id}
                className="collection-item left-align red lighten-3"
              >
                <h5>User ID: {post.id}</h5>
                <p>Post: {post.body}</p>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div className="jumbotron-div col s12">
          <ul className="collection">
            {this.state.comments.map(comment => (
              <li
                key={comment.id}
                className="collection-item left-align purple lighten-2"
              >
                <p>User ID: {comment.id}</p>
                <p>Post: {comment.body}</p>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Postlist;
```

In The Previous code snippet I made 2 requests to the api endpoints and set them to the states posts and comments, Inside render() function the list of posts and comments successfully renders but it listed all posts then all comments, and I need each post with its comments

Comment: nest within the first list another list with comments filtered by `post.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest 2 maps. Just if you want a comment inside a post you need to nest your HTML tags inside each other and then call the map from inside the other one.

```js
class Postlist extends React.Component {
    state = {
        posts: [],
        comments: []
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`).then(res => {
            const posts = res.data;
            this.setState({ posts });
        });

        axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments`).then(res => {
            const comments = res.data;
            this.setState({ comments });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="jumbotron-div col s12">
                    <ul className="collection">
                        {this.state.posts.map(post =>
                            (
                                <div>
                                    <li
                                        key={post.id}
                                        className="collection-item left-align red lighten-3"
                                    >
                                        <h5>User ID: {post.id}</h5>
                                        <p>Post: {post.body}</p>
                                    </li>
                                    <div className="jumbotron-div col s12">
                                        <ul className="collection">
                                            {
                                                this.state.comments.map(comment => (
                                                    <li
                                                        key={comment.id}
                                                        className="collection-item left-align purple lighten-2"
                                                    >
                                                        <p>User ID: {comment.id}</p>
                                                        <p>Post: {comment.body}</p>
                                                    </li>
                                                )
                                                )
                                            }
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            ))
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Postlist name="World" />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/136436/)